# Pattern Matching in Scala Play Controller

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a toy function defined as follows:

```
case class Foo (a : Int, b : String)

def get(): Either[String, Future[Option[Foo]]] = {
  Right(Future.successful(Some(Foo(1, "ABS"))))
}
```

In the Scala Play controller, I attempt to pattern match on the result of this function call:

```
  def hello() : Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
    get() match {
      case Right(x) => x.map{
        case foo => Ok(Json.toJson(foo))
        case None => NoContent
      }
      case Left(x) => InternalServerError(x)
    }
  }
```

The problem is the last Left case statement. If I omit it, then everything type checks. But as soon as I add that Left case statement to handle the error condition, it breaks as the code does not type check anymore. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You are not returning a `Future` from your left case, and your `InternalServerError` wont be automatically wrapped, so you have to do this way:

```
  case Left(x) => Future.successful(InternalServerError(x))
```

Comment: Why is it not necessary to wrap the `Ok` and `NoContent` case clauses?

Comment: Because the `Right` case is already a `Future` and you are calling `map` on it (examine the type of `x` in the two cases).

Comment: you might want to return Future[Either[String, Option[Foo]]] if that makes sense in your business logic, it seems more natural to me, and it's easier to handle by the caller